# javascript drag and drop to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm creating a drag and drop image uploader where I drag an image file into a div and get a preview of the image before it's uploaded.

I have some plain JavaScript that does the job but I want to convert into jQuery.

I've had a go but when I drag the image file into the div, it opens the image in a new tab instead of inside the div.

Here is the original version

```
<div id="document_front">
    <img src="" class="img-responsive">
    <span class="message">
      <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
    </span>
</div>
<input type="file" name="userprofile_picture" id="document_front" />

<script>
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('document_front');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        $imageLoader.find('span').remove();
        $imageLoader.find('img').attr('src', event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

}

var dropbox;
dropbox = document.getElementById("document_front");
dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  //this code line fires your 'handleImage' function (imageLoader change event)
  imageLoader.files = files;
}
</script>
```

and my attempt at converting to jQuery

```
<script>

var $imageLoader = $('#document_front');

$imageLoader.on('change', function() {
    handleImage();
});

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      $imageLoader.find('span').remove();
        $imageLoader.find('img').attr('src', event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

}

$imageLoader.on('dragenter', function() {
  dragenter();
});

$imageLoader.on('dragover', function() {
  dragenter();
});

$imageLoader.on('drop', function() {
  drop();
});

function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  $imageLoader.files[0] = files;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this work fine in plain javascript?

Comment: Yes...this works fine. I'm pretty sure it's the drop function that doesn't work properly....no errors